# How can I automate image slideshow in my existing html code. I need it to work with both, the buttons and automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to automate this image slideshow on the website I'm creating as an assignment. The automatic slideshow should work while it can also work with the buttons (labels) which are here currently.
Currently, it is only made with HTML and CSS, CSS3 code, even a javascript implementation is okay.
Thanks.

```css
body { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: gray;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  min-width: 100vw;
}

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px; 
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.header a.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }
}
.slideshow{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 90vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.middle{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.navigation{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 70px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    display: flex;
}

.bar{
    width: 50px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    margin: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.bar:hover{
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.slides{
    width: 500%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.slide{
    width: 20%;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

.slide img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

input[name="r"]{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#r1:checked ~ .s1{
    margin-left: 0;
}
#r2:checked ~ .s1{
    margin-left: -20%;
}
#r3:checked ~ .s1{
    margin-left: -40%;
}
#r4:checked ~ .s1{
    margin-left: -60%;
}
#r5:checked ~ .s1{
    margin-left: -80%;
}

.title{
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  left:10%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 400;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.title i {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: montserrat-hairline;
  font-weight: 200;
  opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="header">
        <img src="images/logo2.jpg" alt="logo">
        <div class="header-right">
            <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="slideshow middle">
        <div class="slides">
            <input type="radio" name="r" id="r1" checked>
            <input type="radio" name="r" id="r2">
            <input type="radio" name="r" id="r3">
            <input type="radio" name="r" id="r4">
            <input type="radio" name="r" id="r5">
            
            <div class="slide s1">
                <div class="title">Brave  <i>(2012)</i></div>
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516563670759-299070f0dc54?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="brave">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <div class="title">The Hobbit  <i>(2012)</i></div>
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1603791239531-1dda55e194a6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="hobbit">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <div class="title">The Avengers  <i>(2012)</i></div>
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524447466422-e1b709b80a08?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" alt="avengers">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <div class="title">The dark knight  <i>(2008)</i></div>
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535949228921-80c784a22c9f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=889&q=80" alt="dark-knight">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <div class="title">Pirates of the Caribbean  <i>(2003)</i></div>
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564849444446-f876dcef378e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" alt="pirates">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="navigation">
            <label for="r1" class="bar"></label>
            <label for="r2" class="bar"></label>
            <label for="r3" class="bar"></label>
            <label for="r4" class="bar"></label>
            <label for="r5" class="bar"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/Eliteware/full/BoBgqV/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use slick carousel it's much easier and optional

[Silck Carousel](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Answer (score 1):

There is what you need. A carousel made with javascript with previous and next buttons as well as auto slide
[Image slider](https://github.com/iahmadhabibx/mydailyjavascript/tree/master/full-page-image-slider)